# Alargar la barra del select

Tags: html

Tengo un select y queria que ocupase todo el ancho del formulario.

```html
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />       
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: black">
        </br>  </br>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 h-50" style="background-color:#fff;border: 25px solid green">                    
                    <div class="">                       
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend class="text-center header">Formulario IMC</legend>
                            <p>Rellene los campos y pulse calcular</p> 
                            <form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${personForm}" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">     
                                    <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i></span>
                                    <div class="col-md-24"> 
                                        <select th:field="*{sexo}" name="Sexo">
                                            <option th:value="'Hombre'">Hombre</option>
                                            <option th:value="'Mujer'">Mujer</option>
                                        </select>                                  
                                    </div>     
                                    <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i></span>
                                    <div class="col-md-24">
                                        <input th:field="*{edad}" id="edad" type="number" placeholder="Edad" class="form-control">
                                        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('edad')}" th:errors="*{edad}">Error</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-phone-square bigicon"></i></span>
  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#                                  <div class="col-md-24">
                                        <input th:field="*{altura}" id="altura " type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Altura " class="form-control">
                                        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('altura')}" th:errors="*{altura}">Error</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-phone-square bigicon"></i></span>
                                    <div class="col-md-24">
                                        <input th:field="*{peso}" id="peso " type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Peso" class="form-control">
                                        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('peso')}" th:errors="*{peso}">Error</div>
                                    </div>                                    
                                </div> 
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-22 text-center">
                                        <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block bg-sucess" style="background-color: green" >Calcular</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </fieldset>                        
                    </div>
                </div>              
                <div class="col">                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </br>  </br>
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: añade le `width: 100%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo único que te falta es agregarle la clase `form-control` al **select**:

```
<div class="col-md-24">
    <select th:field="*{sexo}" name="Sexo" class="form-control">
        <option th:value="'Hombre'">Hombre</option>
        <option th:value="'Mujer'">Mujer</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <body style="background-color: black">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 h-50" style="background-color:#fff;border: 25px solid green">     
                    <div class="">                       
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend class="text-center header">Formulario IMC</legend>
                            <p>Rellene los campos y pulse calcular</p> 
                            <form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${personForm}" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">     
                                    <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i></span>
                                    <div class="col-md-24"> 
                                        <select th:field="*{sexo}" name="Sexo" class="form-control">
                                            <option th:value="'Hombre'">Hombre</option>
                                            <option th:value="'Mujer'">Mujer</option>
                                        </select>                                  
                                    </div>     
                                    <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i></span>
                                    <div class="col-md-24">
                                        <input th:field="*{edad}" id="edad" type="number" placeholder="Edad" class="form-control">
                                        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('edad')}" th:errors="*{edad}">Error</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-phone-square bigicon"></i></span>
                                   <div class="col-md-24">
                                        <input th:field="*{altura}" id="altura " type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Altura " class="form-control">
                                        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('altura')}" th:errors="*{altura}">Error</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-phone-square bigicon"></i></span>
                                    <div class="col-md-24">
                                        <input th:field="*{peso}" id="peso " type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Peso" class="form-control">
                                        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('peso')}" th:errors="*{peso}">Error</div>
                                    </div>                                    
                                </div> 
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-22 text-center">
                                        <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block bg-sucess" style="background-color: green" >Calcular</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </fieldset>                        
                    </div>
                </div>              
                <div class="col">                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Se podria poner que en vez de hombre y mujer saliera predeterminado el mensaje SEXO y la desplegar elegir entre hombre y mujer? no se si me explico

Comment: @unknow con un option adicional: `<option selected disabled hidden>SEXO</option>`.

Comment: Gracias pero se ve que para la libreria thymeleaf de springboot no vale ese codigo de htlm

Comment: @unknow prueba con: `<option value="" th:disabled="disabled" th:selected="selected">Sexo</option>`.

Comment: ahora si carga pero aparece la opcion pero al desplegar, sin desplegar sale hombre y no SEXO